# Problem with Paypal Express in Chrome with shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am running Magento 1.9.3. CE. I have a strange problem but only in Chrome browser and only when using Guest checkout. I have PayPal Pro with Paypal Express included.

If my item has shipping and choose Paypal Express at checkout, I get the paypal login and try to login but then I get the error message from paypal "We’re Sorry. Things don’t appear to be working at the moment."

If I try to checkout the same way but with an item with free shipping there is no problem at all. As mentioned this only happens in chrome (I have V65) and for guest checkout.

Any help greatly appreciated.